# PHP-AJAX-JSON Notice: Undefined index :

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a test page for sending google map cordinates to populate a mysql database. I'm using ajax to send data to php. Firebug shows that the data is sending. But this php error comes out. And the mysql database is populating without the map cordinates.

Here's the Ajax function:

```
function sendData(geodata){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST","getdata.php",true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");

    if(hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
            var data =  JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            alert("Data received about "+data);
            }//end if

    hr.send("geodata="+geodata);
}//close sendData
```

This is the PHP page.

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type : application/json");

$loc = $_POST["geodata"];

$username="root";
$password="";
$database="location";

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
if(!$connection){
    die('Unable to connect to the server '.mysql_error());
    }

$selectdb = mysql_select_db($database);
if(!$selectdb){
    die('Unable to connect to database'.mysql_error());
    }

$query = "INSERT INTO `location_data`(`ltlng`) VALUES ('".$loc."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
    die('Invalid query : '.mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Then the following errors comes out.

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: geodata in C:\wamp\www\IndustryProject\SampleDataGen\getdata.php on line 4
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Lower your error reporting level, undefined index references generate notices.

Comment: We don't see where you are setting the variable `geodata` which is passed to your function `sendData()`. Post more of the JavaScript, where that function is actually called...

Answer (score 2):

When you're POSTing the data as a query-string, try using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-type, not the `application/json` one that you currently are:

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```